# send PHP confirmation email contact form without using action=""

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I needed to replace a contact form on a website, I used to use a confirmation email sent through PHP in the previous contact form because the attribute action was empty so I could keep the php code on the same page. This is m previous contact form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

    <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00Db0000000IeRo">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://business.mytaxi.ie/thankyou.php">

    <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" required="" type="email" value="" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);" placeholder="email"/>
    <a href="" class="bannerbutsub" title="get started for free.">get started for free.</a>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register Interest" title="Register Interest" class="bannerbutsub">

</form>
```

And this is my php code:

```
if($_POST['email']){
    $q = "INSERT INTO entries (email, datetime) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."',now())";
    $r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());


// sending confirmation email

$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Registration Confirmation';
$from = 'ireland.business@mytaxi.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<p>Hi there,</p>';
$message .= '<p>Thanks for registering your interest in mytaxi | Business.</p>';
$message .= '<p>Our corporate service offers individuals and organisations complete visibility on taxi spend with on-demand automated reporting and as Ireland’s largest and only nationwide network, wait times are as low as 4 minutes.  There’s options available to suit everyone: from enterprise organisations to SME\'s to individuals. </p>';
$message .= '<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGDxs9Xf0jA" target="_new"><img src="http://business.mytaxi.ie/youtube.jpg"></a></p>';
$message .= '<p>A member of our corporate team will be touch with you shortly.</p>';
$message .= '<p>Many Thanks, <br>mytaxi | Business Team</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
// Sending email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

It worked fine but then I was asked to replace the contact form with a new one

Here the new contact form:

```
                        <form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="GET">

                        <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00Db0000000IeRo">
                        <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://business.mytaxi.ie/thankyou.php">

                        <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" required="" type="email" value="" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this);" oninput="InvalidMsg(this);" placeholder="email"/>

                        <input type="hidden" id="lead_source" name="lead_source" value="Web" />

                        <input type="hidden" id="country" name="country" value="Ireland" />

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register Interest" title="Register Interest" class="bannerbutsub">


                        </form>
```

As you can see, in the new contact form there is a URL in the attribute Action="" of the contact form so the confirmation email doesn't work anymore.
I can't take out the value because it is needed. Is there a different way to keep the new contact form and keep sending the confirmation email once the user submits the CF?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the sending of confirmation email now needs to be handled over at:
    https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8

There are hacky ways around this... you could empty the action again so it submits to your script, then use curl to make your script re-submit the data to 
    https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8
and send then email based on the response.

You could also send an ajax request to your script on form submission, where your script handles the sending of the email.

But these are both very hacky, and ultimately the job of responding/informing the user of the success/failure of the form submission is the responsibility of the script the form data is being submitted to.